# Why does the location of the string reference itself change?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string[] names = {"avinash","harish", "savan", "shyam" };
foreach (var name in names)
    namesAll += name;
```

We know that string is immutable in .NET. Each time we concatenate a new string to an existing string, a new memory location is reserved which contains the new concatenated string...which is pointed to by the string reference. This seems fine to me.

What stumps me is why should the the location of the string reference (namesAll) also change? To me this seems completely unnecessary. You can ascertain this in Visual Studio using the Memory window to look at the location of the string reference (namesAll).

Here's the address of namesAll after each iteration: 0x01ef9594 0x01ef961c 0x01ef9644 Please note, this is not the address of the concatenating string (which will obviously change), but the address of the string reference namesAll.

Comment: What do you mean by the "location of the string reference?"  What string it's referring to?  Well of course it's going to change, you are reassigning what string it is referring to.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Uh, he knows. He just recited that in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Bolt: But it doesn't explain what he meant in the quoted phrase.  ;)

Comment: I guess an elaboration of my question is warranted here. Here's the address of namesAll after each iteration:
0x01ef9594
0x01ef961c
0x01ef9644

Please note, this is not the address of the concatenating string (which will obviously change), but the address of the string reference namesAll.

Comment: I made a mistake understanding how the Memory window of Visual Studio works! Sorry!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A specific string will get a reference that is reused anywhere the string is used. Changing the value referenced will change all these other locations as well, hardly what you want...

As a new string is created in each iteration, a new string gets a new memory location - this is referenced by the variable, hence the new address.

Comment: Strings are not automatically interned; interning is available. Consider: `var a = "Alice"; var b = "Bob"; var x = a + b; var y = a + b; bool isSameRef = object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);`. To intern, you have to do `var x = string.Intern( a + b )` and the same for `y`. Then the reference will be the same.

Comment: Sorry, even though the string interning explanation is great, I think this has pretty much nothing to do with the original question. Runtime generated strings are not interned by default. As Jeff pointed out, the answer is already in the question : a new memory location is reserved so this new memory location has a new address... or I'm really missing something here.

Comment: @Joel - from [`String.Intern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx): _The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program._

Comment: @Oded: the keyword here is *literal*. The example further down on the same page says "In the following example, the string s1, which has a value of "MyTest", is already interned because it is a literal in the program.". This sentence clearly expresses that not every string is interned (which would be quite a performance disaster, plus no GC for any string). This MSDN article is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx)

See the link for a full explanation, but here are the details about moving references:

"When a garbage collection is triggered, the garbage collector reclaims the memory that is occupied by dead objects. **The reclaiming process compacts live objects so that they are moved together**, and the dead space is removed, thereby making the heap smaller. This ensures that objects that are allocated together stay together on the managed heap, to preserve their locality."